# How to handle CancellationToken in Azure function eventhub trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, cancellation-token

In an Azure function event hub trigger (v3) it takes in a cancellation token in the `Run` method. When cancellation is signaled it means the server it shutting down. If I send this token to for example a `Get` operation using `httpClient` it will throw a `TaskCanceledException` and the function will end.

Will the events that this function was processing be sent to another instance of the function on another server or are they lost? Should cancellation be handle in a different way?

```
[FunctionName(nameof(MyFunction)), FixedDelayRetry(10, "00:00:15")]
public async Task RunAsync(
   [EventHubTrigger("%InEventHubName%", 
     Connection = "InEventHubConnectionString", 
     ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")] 
   EventData[] events,
   PartitionContext partitionContext,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
       foreach (var ev in events)
       {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.com/fetch?key=" + ev.Properties["Key"],
                             cancellationToken);
            await Process(response, cancellationToken);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the events that this function was processing be sent to another instance of the function on another server or are they lost?

[They are lost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reliable-event-processing):

> Unhandled exceptions may cause you to lose messages. Executions that result in an exception will continue to progress the pointer.

---

> Should cancellation be handle in a different way?

You could choose to ignore cancellation. That may be best for this kind of situation.

Comment: When I read the page you're referring to, I read 

"Unhandled exceptions may cause you to lose messages. Executions that result in an exception will continue to progress the pointer. Setting a retry policy will delay progressing the pointer until the entire retry policy has been evaluated."

Shouldn't the retry policy ensure that these messages are not lost? If not, then what is the point of the retry policy?

Comment: The retry policy will retry. But if the retry also fails, the message is still lost.